# What is the best way to interact when the upload was interrupted?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, asihttprequest

I'm using `ASIHTTPRequest` for uploading photos to the server and it works well but when the connection is lost the upload is interrupted. So what's the best way to deal with this issue? Should this issue be supported by the server to invalidate the request?

Answer (score 4):

That should be handled by `iPhone` side.  When Request is failed due to interruption you should have a bit column to uploading items.

When item failed to upload don't update that bit. When item gets upload you need to update that bit flag so that you know that item is uploaded.

**EDIT**

You should use delegate methods of ASIHTTPRequest didFinish or didFailed. In that method you will keep track whether item uploaded or not.

e.g. You have created Model class like ClsPhoto in which 2 properties are there 1 is UIImage and other is BOOL.

Now if photo is uploaded create BOOL variable true and don't worry about it. If not uploaded keep it to False and upload again prompting user like your upload was interrupted you would like to continue.

This can be done using `Core Data` or using `SQLITE` database or without them keeping those in Memory or `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: How can i handle it with ASIHTTPRequest or should i use another library?

Comment: but the problem is sometimes the photo is upload but the request is not completely done so if i redo it again i will have a redundancy of this photo on on the server so how can i handle that?